# why does a capybara element that clearly has a class return false with has_css?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I thought I could conveniently have a test like:

```
expect(node).to have_css('.ng-hide')
```

However, this fails-- even though it has the css, and it's visible.  I do not understand why this is?  The documentation says "Checks if a given CSS selector is on the page or current node."

```
[12] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> first('.file-row button')[:class]
=> "btn-remove close ng-hide"
[13] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> first('.file-row button').has_css?(‘.ng-hide’)
=> false
[14] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>)> first('.file-row button').visible?
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `#has_css?` will look within the node, but not at the level of the node. I had a similar problem, and using `#parent` zoomed out one level:

```
first('.slide')
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="li">
first('.slide')[:class]
=> "selected"
first('.slide').visible?
=> true
first('.slide').has_css? '.selected'
=> false
first('.slide').parent.has_css? '.selected'
=> true
first('.slide').parent
=> #<Capybara::Document>
```

but the parent of the node seemed to be the entire document.

So, I ended up rewriting my expect statement:

```
expect(first('.slide')[:class]).to include 'selected'
=> true
```